# Getting 404 Page When Attempting to Edit Page/Posts with Fresh Install of Avada/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I set up a new Wordpress (6.2.2) website and installed the latest fresh plugins for Avada Builder (3.11.2) and Avada Core (5.11.2).

With the 2 plugins enabled, when I attempt to edit a page or post (just simply clicking on 'edit' for a page or post), it displays a 404 page.  Viewing the pages/posts work perfectly fine.

I've tried the standard suggested solution which is to reset the permalinks and checking the .htaccess file, but none of that seems to work.

With the Avada plugins disabled, I am able to access the edit pages again.

Does anyone know any other solutions I can try to get edit page/post to work with Avada enabled?

In permalinks settings, I have it set to use the 'Post name' Permalink structure and here's my .htaccess file if it's relevant:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to .htaccess resolved the issue:

```
<IfModule mod_substitute.c> 
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M 
</IfModule>
```